# Extract file from maven dependencies

Tags: android, maven

I have multiple `Maven` dependencies in my project and in one of them there is file with string resources. How can access this file at runtime?
What I am really asking is what is the file path for this file.

Structure might look like this:

```
External Libraries
       |
       dependency.jar
              |
               myfile.properties
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go via:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/myfile.properties");
```